# Is there a way not to generate a refresh token in the WSO2 JWT Grant flow?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using [JWT Grant](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/JWT+Grant#JWTGrant-UsingtheJWTgrant) to exchange a JWT token generated by an external Identity Provider for a WSO2 access token.

The client that will do this is a public browser so I don't want to have a refresh_token. Is there way to configure WSO2 API Manager so that it doesn't generate a refresh_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the JWT grant type and disable refresh token like this[1].

In `AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java`

```
@Override
public boolean issueRefreshToken() throws IdentityOAuth2Exception {
    return false;
}
```

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/token/handlers/grant/AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java#L90

Comment: Sounds good, but how can I reference the new class so that it replaces the original? I mean I guess I should put it in a jar and place it...where?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the refresh token grant handler inside "repository/conf/identity/identity.xml" file. This will globally disable the refresh token grant handler.

```
<SupportedGrantType>
    <GrantTypeName>refresh_token</GrantTypeName>
    <GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.RefreshGrantHandler</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>
</SupportedGrantType>
```

Comment: I wouldnt like to remove it globally...is there a way to apply that only to my particular JWT Grant scenario?